# Whenever I post a blog in wordpress,a new link gets published automatically along with pricing word and its broken

Tags: php, wordpress

Consider that you are publishing a blog in wp today. We get a URL as wwww.example.com/blog/how-does-this-happen/. When I audit the site, I found a 404 page with the same URL but with a word pricing at the end like wwww. example.com/blog/how-does-this-happen/pricing. This happens for WP posts that I publish. All broken links are the ones with the pricing word at the end

Permalink was fine and I tried to migrate to the new domain too but still the problem persists since it is in the source code and I don't know how to find it

Comment: So where exactly are you finding those URLs/ links? If something generates these as part of the post content that gets generated, then it is probably some plugin doing that ...?

Comment: I found those links using the Ahref and Dr. linkcheck site. I don't know which plugin cause this problem

Comment: We can hardly know any more than you at this point, with what little information we have here. Try and disable plugins one by one then, until something changes.